# testing if my jms listener is working

Tags: jms

i want to test if my jms listener is working perfectly 
when sending 5 messages ( for example ) i added a timer
"Threat.sleep(5000)" and after 5 seconds i want to compare the old messageID with the new messageID that means i want to know if the messages are listened or not so if the ID changes that means that they are successfuly listened

here is my OnMessage code ... but  it doesnt work for me :((

```
public class Consumer implements MessageListener{

public Consumer() {
}

//@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {


    try {

         TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) message;

        int i;
        TextMessage tm2 =tm;
                            for(i=0;i<1;i++)
                            {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            if (!tm.getJMSMessageID().equals(tm2.getJMSMessageID()))
            { 
                System.out.println("\t----Listener not working----");
            }
            else {

            System.out.println("Message reçu:");
            System.out.println("\tTemps:       " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " ms");
            System.out.println("\tMessage ID: " + tm.getJMSMessageID());
            System.out.println("\tCorrel. ID: " + tm.getJMSCorrelationID());
            System.out.println("\tConsumed message:   " + tm.getText());
                            System.out.println("\t----Listener working----");
            }
            //fin else
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
                            }

    } 
    catch (JMSException jex) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + jex);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're checking the JMS message id to ensure that no two messages have identical id's? This is probably overkill since, if your listener is receiving messages, it's working!...Nevertheless, your approach has a few problems....

```
  TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) message;
  ...     
  TextMessage tm2 =tm;
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  if (!tm.getJMSMessageID().equals(tm2.getJMSMessageID()))
```

The above `if()` will always be false because you're comparing the same message; also, the `sleep()` statement is useless.

If you want to compare message id's to ensure they are always unique, although if the broker fails to deliver a message the same message will be redelivered and the id would be the same, but anyway, you can use this an an alternative to your code..

```
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> mesgIdMap = 
  new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

public Consumer() {
}

//@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) message;

        if( mesgIdMap.contains( tm.getJMSMessageID()))
           System.out.println("\tProcessing JMS message with same ID again!");

        //add the message id to the map
        mesgIdMap.put( tm.getJMSMessageID(),tm.getJMSMessageID());
        //print statements here...
```